# Ignore errors in ForEach-Object loop

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have a text file full of TV shows with an ID at the end of their name in each line of a text document.
I want to ignore any blank line or ignore any errors

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\test\text.txt" | ForEach-Object  {
    $_.Substring($_.Length - 5) -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
}
```

I tried to suppress any errors like this but that didn't resolve the issue. How can I skip blank lines or suppress the error messages in a foreach loop?

Comment: The parameter `-ErrorAction` can be used with cmdlets, but not with object methods.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the error action variable globally before your code, and then set it back to it's previous value afterwards:

```
$PrevErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'

Get-Content -Path  "C:\test\text.txt" | ForEach-Object  {
    $_.Substring($_.Length - 5)
}

$ErrorActionPreference = $PrevErrorActionPreference
```

Alternatively, just use an `If` statement to test for the Length of the string before using `SubString`:

```
Get-Content -Path "*.txt" | ForEach-Object  {
    If ($_.Length -ge 5) { $_.Substring($_.Length - 5) }
}
```

A third option would be to use a `Try..Catch` block:

```
Get-Content -Path "*.txt" | ForEach-Object  {
    Try {
        $_.Substring($_.Length - 5)
    } Catch {
        # Do nothing
    }
}
```